# Got a "Fatal Error : Failed to connect to CPU Session aborted !" in IAR IDE

Tags: iar, cmsis

I use CMSIS-DAP link for debugging and CMSIS-DAP firmware load successfully.

and I use IAR Workbench Version 7.80 IDE.

I can build code successfully.

But after I Got a **"Fatal Error : Failed to connect to CPU Session aborted !"** during **"Download and Debug"** a code from IAR IDE.

I could not find any solution behind this issue.

So,Please reply me.

Regards,
Pratik

Comment: "But after.." after what?

Comment: I got an error during downloading. if this fatal error solve then CMSIS-DAP connect with IAR IDE and I can debug and run my code easily.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to check the following 2 settings in your project options:

1. in project Options, Category:Debugger-> Setup->Driver, make sure you set driver setup to whatever driver youre using. I gave an I-jet and I set driver to I-jet
2. in project Options, Category-> I-jet, Interface, select Probe Confog to Auto and Interface to SWD

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following,

1. Make sure the controller is fully powered and not entering the sleep mode within few seconds of no communication.
2. Performing POR to wake the controller incase of CPU off.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error. Turns out, I had rotated the JTAG cable the wrong way around. I rotated the JTAG connector 180 degrees. I was then able to download to the target and run the software.